# Have $watch trigger other function in object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, watch

I want to have an object which can listen to certain parts of it using $watch but then call another member function whenever the watch is triggered. I'm not sure if the way I am currently approaching it even lends any possible solution:

```
  Foo.prototype.onChange = function onChange() {
      console.log(this);
  };

  Foo.prototype.addWatch = function addWatch() {
    $rootScope.$watch(bind(this, function() {
      return this.varsToWatch[someArbitraryWatchedVar];
    }) , this.onChange, true);
  };
```

When I call onChange within a normal function in Foo, the output of the console log is `Foo {...correct object...}` however when the addWatch triggers it, the console logs `Object {fn: function, last: "asdf", get: function, exp: function, eq: true}` which is not at all related to my `Foo` object. I would like to be able to call onChange and manipulate my `Foo` object with `$watch` calls!

Comment: i.e because onChange is called from within the angular scope meaning that will be the context.. Try `bind(this.onChange, this)` or `_this = this` before the watch and remove `bind` and use  `,function(){_this.onChange.apply(_that, arguments)}`, `_this.varsToWatch...` on the watch

Comment: Where exactly would these arguments go? Would the $watch statement look like ```$rootScope.$watch( _this.varsToWatch, function(){_this.onChange.apply(_that, arguments)}, true);```